# Lua function getting different datatype when given a number

Tags: lua

I have this problem in a Lua class. Here is the code of my class:

```
local Temp = {}             

function Temp:new(tmp)             
  local self = {temp = -273.15}    
  if tmp > self.temp then       
    self.temp = tmp
  end

  local setC = function(usrTmp)
    if usrTmp < -273.15 then
      self.temp = -273.15
    else
      self.temp = usrTmp
    end
  end

  local getC = function()         
    return self.temp
  end

  local getF = function()
    return self.temp * 1.8 + 32
  end

  local getK = function()
    return self.temp + 273.15
  end

  return {                       
    setC = setC,                  
    getC = getC,                   
    getF = getF,
    getK = getK
  }
end

return Temp
```

And here is my main method:

```
temp = require "tempClass"

io.write("Please enter the initial temperature: ")
usrTemp = io.read("*n")

myTemp = temp:new(usrTemp)

print("The current temperature in Celsius is: ".. myTemp:getC())
print("The current temperature in Fahrenheit is: " .. myTemp:getF())
print("The current temperature in Kelvin is: " .. myTemp:getK())
io.write("Please enter new temperature: ")
changeTemp = io.read("*n")
myTemp:setC(changeTemp)
print("The current temperature in Celsius is: " .. myTemp:getC())
print("The current temperature in Fahrenheit is: " .. myTemp:getF())
print("The current temperature in Kelvin is: " .. myTemp:getK())
io.write("Please enter new temperature: ")
```

My problem is the `if usrTmp < -273.15 then` line in the `setC` function. I'm getting this error message:

```
lua: ./tempClass.lua:10: attempt to compare table with number
stack traceback:
    ./tempClass.lua:10: in function 'setC'
    [string "<eval>"]:14: in main chunk
```

I know, however, that `usrTmp` is a number. If I call `type` on the variable before the function, I get type `number`. In the function, the type is `table`. Why is `usrTmp` a table in the function? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be explicit about the `self` parameter when defining functions that shall be used with it. The function `setC` should have an additional such parameter:

```
local setC = function(self, usrTmp)
  -- as before...
 end
```

Recall that these two invocations are identical:

```
myTemp:setC(changeTemp)
myTemp.setC(myTemp, changeTemp)
```

That should explain the actual error message your received.

---

In addition, you need to turn `Table.new` into an ordinary (not `self`-parameter-enhanced) function. It's not connected to an instance yet, it is supposed to return one. And finally, the state variable `temp` must be included in the table that `Table.new` returns:

```
function Temp.new(tmp)
  --         ^ note the dot instead of the colon

  -- function body as before, but all functions now need the self parameter, e.g.:
  local getC = function(self)
     return self.temp
  end


  return {
    temp = self.temp,
    setC = setC,
    getC = getC,
    getF = getF,
    getK = getK
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've added self to the function, and the error message is gone but the temp value doesn't change. Do I need to give self to all functions in the class?

Comment: Yes, and you also have to pass the temperature back to the caller, at the end of `Table.new`. See the edit.

Comment: Ah ok I see, so what's the difference between the . and the :? Also thank you very much, great answer!

Comment: W.r.t. your last question. The `:` is nothing but a syntactic shortcut for adding the part left of `:` as the first argument to the following function. You can achieve the same when you use the `.` and pass the instance manually.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thank you! Lastly, and this is kind of off topic, but can you override the tostring in the .bew function?

Comment: I don't get that part. You might want to post a new question for that?